# Can a trajectory pass through a critical point for a plane autonomous system? (Differential equations)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stationary-point

**Set up:**

I am considering a plane autonomous system where there exists two ODEs, $\frac{dx}{dt}=X(x,y),\frac{dy}{dt}=Y(x,y)$. We then usually draw trajectories on the phase plane to indicate the solutions on the plane.

**Question**:

I often see trajectories sometimes cross at critical points, however I was wondering, if a trajectory does contain a critical point, wouldn't this trajectory just stay at that critical point rather than passing through that critical point since at that point $X=Y=0$ and so just becomes stationary?

I am not too sure if I made much sense with my question but any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest example is
$${dx\over dt}=x,\quad {dy\over dt}=-y\ .$$
When ${\bf r}(0)=(x_0,0)$, $\>x_0\ne0$,  then $${\bf r}(t)=(x_0e^t,0)\qquad(-\infty<t<\infty)\ ,$$ hence the *half* $x$-axis containing $x_0$ is a solution curve. Similarly, when ${\bf r}(0)=(0,y_0)$, $\>y_0\ne0$, then 
$${\bf r}(t)=(0,y_0e^{-t})\qquad(-\infty<t<\infty)\ ,$$ hence the *half* $y$-axis containing $y_0$ is a solution curve. But note that this curve reaches $(0,0)$ only in the limit $t\to\infty$. This means that the traveling point needs infinite time to reach the origin. And of course the initial condition ${\bf r}(0)=(0,0)$ leads to ${\bf r}(t)=(0,0)$ for all $t$.

Therefore no trajectory "traverses" the stationary point $(0,0)$.